# UWP XAML How do I wrap text in a bound ListView

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview

How do I wrap or otherwise display long strings in my listview control.  I have been unsuccessful in wrapping, or otherwise displaying long text in my bound ListView control.  My xaml page is basically a BOUND FlipView with an ItemTemplate that contains two bound textBlocks and a bound ListView.  I can get the TextBlocks to wrap but not the listviewitems.  It would seem like such a simple thing yet it eludes me.

Here is a portion of my xaml:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:MydataObject" x:Key="MydataObjectTemplate">
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="596" Width="982">
            <TextBlock Name="txtDataObjectId" Text="{Binding dataObject.Id}" Visibility="Collapsed" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"/>
            <TextBlock FontSize="24" Text="{x:Bind dataObject}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"/>
            <ListView ItemsSource ="{x:Bind theObjectDetails, Mode=OneWay }" 
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  
                      BorderBrush="Black" 
                      BorderThickness="1"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <ComboBox x:Name="cboCategory" Header="Category" SelectionChanged="cboCategory_SelectionChanged" />
        <FlipView x:Name="FlipView1" 
              ItemsSource="{x:Bind MydataObjects, Mode=OneWay }" 
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MydataObjectTemplate}"
              BorderBrush="Black" 
              BorderThickness="1"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>

//c#
public class mydataObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public dataObject theObject { get; set; }
    public List<dataObjectDetails> theObjectDetails { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.theObject.Subject;
    }
}

public class dataObjectDetails
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int dodId{ get; set; }
    public string bodyText { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return bodyText ;
    }
}
```

Comment: I should have indicated Windows 10 UWP ListView as it might make a difference...

Comment: Are Text strings the only thing you're passing into the ListView for items? Or are you throwing objects in there like Button's or something? If it's just strings you can always specify the listview ItemTemplate with a TextBlock bound to Content and accomplish the goal.

Comment: I am beginning to understand my difficulty.  I am binding the ListView to an object that has an override on the ToString to send the text that appears in the listview.  So the FlipView is bound to a List<MydataObject>  and the ListView is bound to

Comment: Looking at the code you just added, you're binding ListView.ItemsSource to the class name `dataObjectDetails`, rather to the property `theObjectDetails`. Are you seeing the expected items in the ListView?

Comment: I have corrected the above example.  It appears that I was careless when making generic for posting here.

Comment: I think my answer should work. If it does, please click the checkmark next to it. if not, let me know what you're seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the ListView an ItemTemplate, which puts the content in a TextBlock that wraps the text:

```
<ListView
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind theObjectDetails, Mode=OneWay}"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock 
                    Text="{Binding bodyText}"
                    TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"
                    />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: This answer was the solution.  The binding threw me off at first because the Text property needed to be bound to the underlying dataObjectDetails BodyText, or simply to bodyText.